# How can I type in a virtual machine that is located on a host machine that I remote desktop into?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, hyper-v, remote-desktop, virtualbox

I'm using a remote desktop to log in to another computer and on that computer.
Trying to start up a virtual machine. The problem I'm having is when I try to type in the virtual machine, most of the keys on my keyboard don't work. 
For example, certain keys like Space bar will type "d" and my number 1 key would type ";". 
 Most of the other keys don't work. 
I can type fine on the host machine, but can't inside the virtual machine. I tried both VirtualBox and HyperV and both are encountering the same problem. 
Any idea what might be causing this issue? I also remote into a Windows server and had the same issue. The virtual machine is running Ubuntu 18.

Comment: I've done the same with ESXi, and VirtualBox and it worked for me. It sounds like your virtual machines have a different keyboard layout setting than you have keyboard. What keyboard layout do you have: physical, host settings, and VM settings?

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 everything is set to US-English. From my computer to the host machine, it works fine, but the input is messed up from the host machine to the VM. I tested the on-screen keyboard and that works fine

Comment: Normally when adding more detail about the issue you edit your question to reflect the extra detail rather than in a comment. That being said, I'm running low on ideas. Maybe try checking what accessibility settings are in place if any. While checking turn off keyboard shortcuts to turn them on. Maybe look in to if any keyboard remapping is done in Linux. Where did you get the VM from? Did you do the install yourself or download a pre-built VM?